# Dynamo db query list parameter

Tags: dynamodb-queries

I don't know exactly what I am doing wrong with this query. I am querying a dynamo table with entries that look like this:

| id | name | price | tags |

Tags are a list:

```
[ { "S" : "tag1" }, { "S" : "tag2" }, { "S" : "tag3" }]
```

I want to do a query where I want all entries that have any tags within another list of tags. For example, get every entry that has "tag1" or every entry that has "tag1","tag2."

The query I am trying to test with right now is:

```
    {"TableName": "products-lambda-table",
     "FilterExpression": "tags IN (:tags1)",
     "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
     ":tags1": "tag1"
    }
```

This throws back nada (using node, AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient().query(params))

Is there something I'm missing? This is all fairly brand new to me.

Answer (score 0):

Solved on my own, was overthinking something/there was an error elsewhere that was throwing me off.